# Dynamic Multiple textfield reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I have implemented dynamic multiple text field in reactjs,

when i add new row by clicking `add` button,
enter the key textfield and enter the value textfield,
click on `+` icon does not add row .

can help, here is codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-neumann-ov2wj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleValueChange = (event, row, i) => {
var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...this.state.additionalFields]));
newArray[row.id].value[i] = event.target.value;
this.setState({ additionalFields: newArray });
};
```

Creating a deep copy of the "additionalFields" property in state object seems to have fixed the issue.

One thing I tend to do when copying a reference value that has 1 or more layers of other reference values (objects, arrays) is that I convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify()` and then I convert it back to an object using `JSON.parse()`. This results in an array that does not point to your original array in your state object. Lodash has a more readable way with their `cloneDeep()` method but with vanilla JavaScript you can use my solution.